# Python - create folder with multiple subfolders

Tags: python, directory

I need to create a list of folders each with multiple subfolders that are not nested. I have used

```
os.makedirs('folder/subfolder')
```

to create a folder and a subfolder but I can only make multiple nested folders work:

```
os.makedirs('folder/subfolder1/subfolder2/subfolder3')
```

where sub3 is nested in sub2 which is nested in sub1. What I want is for sub 1, 2 and 3 all to be nested in 'folder' together (3 folders inside 1 folder). I tried

```
os.makedirs('folder/(subfolder1, subfolder2)')
```

but that just creates a folder titled "(*subfolder1, subfolder2)*" Does anyone know the correct syntax for this? Is it even possible with the makedirs function?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Use a loop:

```
for i in range(1,100):
    os.makedirs(os.path.join('folder', 'subfolder' + str(i)))
```

Or, if you have the names in a `list`:

```
subfolder_names = []
for subfolder_name in subfolder_names:
    os.makedirs(os.path.join('folder', subfolder_name))
```

p.s.

In case to ignore already-exist folder

```
os.makedirs('/path/to/dir', exist_ok=True)
```

Comment: Why not `subfolders` and `subfolder`?

Comment: I think it's more descriptive (Just `subfolder` could be anything; a handle, an ID etc.). Anyway, it's just a variable name!

Comment: Awesome, this works. I think I need two loops to create each folder and then create the list of subfolders within each folder.

Comment: How can I create another "level" of subfolders? I mean, I'd like to create a structure like this one: `folder/(subfolder_1, subfolder_2, subfolder_3)` where the subfolder between parenthesis are on the same second level, and then `subfolder_1/(subfolder_1.1, subfolder_1.2)`, `subfolder_2/(subfolder_2.1, subfolder_2.2)`, `subfolder_3/(subfolder_3.1, subfolder_3.2)`?

Answer (score 2):

You can't do it in one call like that.  Just put one call after another:

```
os.makedirs("folder/subfolder1")
os.makedir("folder/subfolder2")
```

Comment: Darn. I have to create subs in about 100 folders. I was hoping it would be quicker.

Comment: You can use a loop to make it faster.  `for subfolder in subfolders: os.makedir(os.path.join("folder", subfolder))`

Answer (score 2):

You can loop using a list comprehension, create the directory at each iteration using `os.mkdir` and assigning it a name that is the result of joining the base path to a given directory name.

```
import os

[os.mkdir(os.path.join("/folder", "subdir{}".format(i))) for i in range(100)]
```

Comment: Could you explain it a bit, please?

Comment: @dawid-ferenczy Sure. It's a list comprehension http://python-3-patterns-idioms-test.readthedocs.org/en/latest/Comprehensions.html with two nested methods from the `os` library.

Comment: No, sorry, I meant if you can edit your answer and add some explanation there (a little bit better than "It's a list comprehension"). It's not for me, rather for preventing the answer deletion in [Low Quality Posts review](http://stackoverflow.com/review/low-quality-posts) and also for others. Stack Overflow users shouldn't just copy&paste answers, but rather understand a problem and be able to solve it themselves. But that means they need some explanation.

Comment: I understand and i'm sorry but the system doesn't allow me to edit the answer

Comment: It doesn't allow to edit your own answer, right? That's weird. I wonder what's the reason for that...

Comment: Yep another user left his editing form open probably. Now i could edit.